# I want to define a variable globally but it should be initialized locally and the data should be the same for other classes

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables, return-value, dataflowtask

```
bool Globalveriable = false;

    class Class1 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Class1State createState() => _Class1State();
    }
    
    class _Class1State extends State<Class1> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DayNightSwitch(
          value: Globalveriable,
          onChanged: (changed) {
            setState(() {
              Globalveriable = changed;
            });
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Class2 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Class2State createState() => _Class2State();
    }
    
    class _Class2State extends State<Class2> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text(Globalveriable.toString());
      }
    }
```

//when clicking on the switch, the value of Globalveriable will be true for Class1 but I want it should be the same for Class2 at the Same time

Answer (score 0):

add the `static` keyword will resolve your issue as

```
static bool Globalveriable = false;
```